# Android Studio Cannot Lock Sytem Folder

Tags: java, android, ide

I'm getting the `Internal Error` shown below. I've found Solutions for `cannot bind child loop`, but not for this error.

I tried the following with no luck. Suggestions appreciated.

- Opened `cmd` window with Run as Administrator option
- Executed `netsh winsock reset` on the command line
- Restarted the computer
- Re-installed software

  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbQTd.jpg): [image]

Comment: What were you specifically running or doing at the time? Is this your code or app or someone else's? Do you know what port is being used and if any other software might be in conflict (already using it)?. Does the application that's getting this error have an option to use a different port? If so, would changing the port # make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by turning off Hyper-V in Windows feature.